# How to reverse engineer kernel configs for a prebuilt kernel?

Tags: kernel-modules, kernel-parameters

I am trying to build a kernel module for a commercial gadget which runs Linux 4.9.x. The kernel module that I build crashes the kernel. I believe this is because of wrong kernel configurations. I have tried different kernel configurations to no avail.

Regular ways of getting kernel configs (/boot/config.gz,  requesting manufacturer for GPL code etc) do not work in this case. Also, the kernel is not built with CONFIG_IKCONFIG.

From this thread - [What are methods for recovering a Linux Kernel config?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304920/what-are-methods-for-recovering-a-linux-kernel-config) - it looks like there is a way to recover kernel configs from /proc/kallsyms.

Can anybody shed light on this? How do kallsyms lead me to kernel configs? What kind of scripting do I need to use?

Comment: Have you tried `modprobe configs`?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel config is not the only thing which is required to compile additional modules.

You also need to know:

- Whether and how it was patched.
- What compiler was used to build it. If you're using a different compiler, ABI might change which will lead to your exact issue.